# What was the battle in which Khalid bin Waleed besieged a city with a trench around it and filled up the trench with camels to cross it?

Tags: history, war, battles

i remember reading about a battle in which the muslim army under Khalid bin Waleed laid siege to a city with a trench around it and Khalid RA had the old and weak camels slaughtered to fill up the trench and cross it. What was the name?

Answer (score 0):

This happened in the battle that is called **Dhat al-'Uyun** or **Al-Anbar**, fought during the caliphate of Abu Bakr, against the Persians.

> فتقدم خالد إلى الخندق فاستدعى برذي الأموال من الإبل فذبحها حتى ردم الخندق بها
>
> <sup>— [Al-Bidaya wa'l-Nihaya](https://shamela.ws/book/4445/5355)</sup>