Question about a battle
Was there a battle that happened in which there was a trench that was filled with dead people and animals to cross over the trench? Is there any record of such a battle? I saw one video on YouTube shorts regarding this battle and just wanted to confirm if this indeed happened.

See https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/74071/

@UmH thanks! I get it now.
